# Normalize a line graph to better show small changes over time

Tags: excel, graph, statistics, normalization

I have a line graph depicting headcount of  my workplace. 
We wanted to start a line graph to depict the trends of people leaving and joining the company, however, we have noticed that there are some trends we already know and are expecting every year and don't want it to reflect in the graph because it masks the real people leaving and coming in. The people we are noticing are interns coming in the summer and leaving, we have about 100 interns every year. I would like to somehow "normalize" my graph so that the big number of interns coming in doesn't cause a spike up and them leaving doesn't cause a big dip. The spikes and dips I want to capture are the people resigning/retiring and the people getting hired.

How would I go about doing this? (I am using excel to produce these graphs)

Comment: The math involved is called "seasonal adjustment".  Here is one implementation that comes up when Googling that.  http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411outbd.htm

Comment: Why not exclude interns from your dataset?